# Code Exiting on above 500,000 number of input

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++14

I was performing sorting algorithm to calculate their runtime to execute, in which I was giving millions of number of input to sort, but my code is exiting on above 500,000 input and not showing any output. Is there anyway I can solve it.

```
int size;
cout<<"Enter size of the array: "<<endl;
cin>>size;
int a[size];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    a[i]=rand()%size;
}
int temp = 0;
double cl=clock();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
    {
        if (a[j] < a[i])
        {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
double final=clock()-cl;
cout<<final/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

}

Comment: Your sorting approach has `O(n^2)` complexity, where `n` is the input size. It times out for large input size

Comment: But it is also exiting from the other sorting code like quick ,insertion, radix etc.

Comment: If your int is 16 bits then 500000 is too big.

Comment: Also tried changing its data type to long, but doesn't work

Comment: @AliHasanKhan you changed it for everything except a and temp?

Comment: @AliHasanKhan then add the most "optimised" approach you've tried, so that other people don't need to guess

Comment: Your array is allocated on the stack. Don't you get a stack overflow message ?

Comment: This `int a[size];` where you input the size by `std::cin >> size;` is called a _variable-length array_ (VLA), which is not a standard C++ feature. VLAs can be implemented as a custom language extension by some compilers. They use stack, and, for example, on Windows, stack has only ~ 1MiB size by default. Don't use VLAs, use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code crashes on 500'000 input because of stack overflow, you're allocating array on stack of too big size:

`int a[size];`

Stack size is usually few megabytes at most.

Also it is probably an extensions not of all compilers to have dynamically allocated array on stack, usually `size` should be a compile time constant.

To overcome stack crash either you have to use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which can provide any size as big as there is free memory, for that do:

`std::vector<int> a(size);`

(also `#include <vector>`). Or you may use dynamically allocated array through [new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) operator:

`int * a = new int[size];`

For this case don't forget to do `delete[] a;` at the end of program (see [docs here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)).

Don't forget that input 500'000 takes very much of time using your bubble sort. For example 10 times less, 50'000, takes around 10 seconds on my machine.

Full working code using `std::vector` plus code formatting:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/hqhYc5Wfd)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int size;
    cout << "Enter size of the array: " << endl;
    cin >> size;
    std::vector<int> a(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % size;
    }
    int temp = 0;
    double cl = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[i]) {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    double final = clock() - cl;
    cout << final / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```